# How to know if i can connect to a network?

Tags: contract-deployment, network

I deployed to Rinkeby, when I connect to Rinkeby everything is ok, but if I change the network (for example Ropsten), I am getting an error that is ok as well because my contract is for Rinkeby.

my question is: how can I know if my wallet can connect to a network?

**for example**:

my contract was deployed for Rinkeby

if I try to connect to Rapsten I will need an error message

Comment: You would run into errors. so you know something. Can you elaborate on what you see here?

Comment: you can check the chain id and check if it is the id of the chain you need to connect to, otherwise warn the user and ask them to connect to the correct network

Comment: @MajdTL how can i check the chain?

Comment: What are you using ? Web3js , metamask or something else?

Comment: @MajdTL iam using web3j, and metamask

Comment: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.4/web3-eth.html?highlight=chainId#getchainid